# Inheriting gradle plugin in subprojects

Tags: gradle, flyway, subproject

I want to avoid redundancy and therefore I got one "shared" project that contains looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "4.2.0"
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: "java"

dependencies {
    compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"

    // ...
}
```

Then I also have my regular projects that inherit the compile dependencies from my shared project like this:

```
apply plugin: "java"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":shared")
    testCompile project(":shared")
}
```

Is there any way I can make my regular projects inherit the plugin block or the actual plugin as well?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Not *inherit* as such. It seems to me that what you're trying to do can be achieved by configuring the subprojects from the root project. Basically in your root `build.gradle` (which script that will configure your root project) you can write:

```
subprojects {
  // configuration
}
```

You can probably get rid of your shared project and have this in root project's `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "4.2.0" apply false
}

subprojects {    
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    apply plugin: "java"
    apply plugin: "org.flywaydb.flyway"

    dependencies {
        compile "commons-io:commons-io:2.4"

        // ...
    }
}
```

This way all your subprojects will be configured using the same closure - this is equivalent to copy-pasting everything in `subprojects` block to your individual subprojects' `build.gradle` files. The advantage over your initial solution is ability to also apply plugins, configure extensions, everything you normally can do.

As a side note, you don't need both `jcenter()` and `mavenCentral` in `repositories` block - `jCenter` is a superset of `mavenCentral` and is the preferred one

Comment: Tried that, but I'm getting:
`Error:(57, 0) Could not find method plugins() for arguments [build_44j4lgef9ftzfeyhh4janhtfy$_run_closure3$_closure14@65b80565] on project ':core' of type org.gradle.api.Project."`

So apparently one cannot use the plugins statement inside subprojects...

Comment: You're correct, i've fixed the answer to work around `plugins` current limitation